# POSIX regex not matching

Tags: c++, regex

This is the first time I tried POSIX regex. I tried the following code but was not getting the expected result. I need to get the numbers alone from the string. I am running the code on Linux Mint, compiled with g++ 4.7.2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main()
{
    int ret;
    char string[512] = "Odd:97531|Even:86420";
    regex_t pattern;

    ret = regcomp(&pattern, "[0-9]*", REG_EXTENDED);
    if(ret < 0) 
    { 
        char err[512] = {};
        regerror(ret, &pattern, err, 500);
        printf("Regex compile error : %s\n", err);
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Number of subexpression : %d\n", pattern.re_nsub);
    }

    int nmatch = 5;
    regmatch_t match[5];
    ret = regexec(&pattern, string, nmatch, match, 0);
    if(ret < 0)
    {
        char err[512] = {};
        regerror(ret, &pattern, err, 500);
        printf("Regex execute error : %s\n", err);
        return -2;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Number of subexpression : %d\n", pattern.re_nsub);
        for(int I = 0; I < nmatch; I++)
            printf("Match %02d : %.*s (%d to %d)\n", I + 1, 
            match[I].rm_eo - match[I].rm_so, string + match[I].rm_so, 
            match[I].rm_so, match[I].rm_eo);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Number of subexpression : 0
Number of subexpression : 0
Match 01 :  (0 to 0)
Match 02 :  (-1 to -1)
Match 03 :  (-1 to -1)
Match 04 :  (-1 to -1)
Match 05 :  (-1 to -1)
```

What am I doing wrong? Some one help me on this.

Comment: Regex are not working until gcc 4.9, use boost::regex.

Comment: @Kiroxas It is not about regex in C++11. It's about POSIX regex.

Comment: If you are using POSIX regex library *and* c++, I wrote a c++ wrapper that abstracts the details away and makes it very similar to python's re module: https://github.com/RPGillespie6/posix-regex-cpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[0-9]*` matches **zero** or more decimal digits. Obviously the beginning of string matches. You may want `[0-9]+` instead, which stands for **one** or more decimal digits.

Furthermore, to match the same pattern for multiple times, you need to call `regexec()` multiple times with different offset. `nmatch` is for the different parenthesis in the regex, not for matching multiple occurrence.

The complete refined code looks like:

```
int main()
{
    int ret;
    char string[512] = "Odd:97531|Even:86420";
    regex_t pattern;

    ret = regcomp(&pattern, "[0-9]+", REG_EXTENDED);
    if(ret != 0)
    {
        char err[512] = {};
        regerror(ret, &pattern, err, 500);
        printf("Regex compile error : %s\n", err);
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Number of subexpression : %d\n", pattern.re_nsub);
    }

    regmatch_t match;
    char *notmatched = string;
    for (int I = 1; regexec(&pattern, notmatched, 1, &match, 0) == 0; ++I) {
        printf("Match %02d : %.*s (%d to %d)\n", I,
                match.rm_eo - match.rm_so, notmatched + match.rm_so,
                match.rm_so, match.rm_eo);
        notmatched += match.rm_eo;
    }

    return 0;
}
```